# Breadth-First-Search for moving dot game

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

Hi I having been trying to program an algorithm using breadth-first-search that finds the shortest path for the blue dot to exit in the game. I am new to java and having trouble running/understanding the algorithm for the class. I have a class called gameModel which stores the statuses of each dot. The algoirthm is meant to test the fastest way the blue dot can exit the board without going through an orange dot (SELECTED) and if no way out than the player wins. I keep running the program and getting compile errors which i dont know how to fix. I included the controller class where the short dot was ran.

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.*;

/**
 * The class <b>GameController</b> is the controller of the game. It implements 
 * the interface ActionListener to be called back when the player makes a move. It computes
 * the next step of the game, and then updates model and view.

*/


public class GameController implements ActionListener {

private int size;
private GameModel gameModel;
private GameView gameView;
private boolean click;

 /**
 * Constructor used for initializing the controller. It creates the game's view 
 * and the game's model instances
 * 
 * @param size
 *            the size of the board on which the game will be played
 */
public GameController(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.gameModel = new GameModel(size);
    this.gameView = new GameView (gameModel, this);
    click =  false;
}


/**
 * Starts the game
 */
public void start(){
    if (click){
        List start = new List {gameModel.getCurrentDot().getX(), gameModel.getCurrentDot().getY()};
        List<int> targets = new ArrayList<>();
        List<int> blocked = nwq ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            targets.add(i, 0);
            targets.add(i, size);
            targets.add(1, size);
            targets.add(1, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                if(gameModel.getstatus(i, j) == SELECTED){
                blocked.add(i, j);
            }
        String path = Breadth-First-Start(start, targets, blocked);
        gameView = new GameView(gameModel, this);
        gameView.getBoardView().update();
    }
}

public Breadth-First-Start(start, targets, blocked){ // Need help with
    Queue queue = new LinkedList();
    queue.add(start + "");

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        String p = queue.remove();
        if (p != blocked){       //If p is not in blocked paths
            if (p == targets){   //If p is in targets
                return "q + {p}";
            } else {
                queue.add("q + {p}");
                blocked.add(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the compile errors? Please add them to the post.

Comment: Sthepanie, it's not related to the question but you have to learn to accept some answers *IF* they solved your problems (or just leaving a comment to indicate that the answers don't work), because this how the site works you don't even have to pay them just accept their answers (yet your questions are mostly `debugging`, they're tough, not easy to solve), by doing that it will trigger people to help you again in the future.

Comment: Do all uOttawa students get other people to do their homework for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method `public Breadth-First-Start(start, targets, blocked)` is declared wrong. You cant have `-` in method name, also you need to specify the return type (only constructors dont have a return type to be defined). Also you need to specify parameter types. From what I understand targets and start look like of type String and blocked looks like a List, please try replace the method head by the following `public void breadthFirstSearch(String start, String targets, List blocked)` not sure what return type you want as you dont have any returns in the method. But in your case you probably want the path so maybe of type List, or a boolean to know if there is a path or not.

Comment: Thank you that fixed a problem

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do has to do with graph theory.  If two nodes are connected, an edge between them is created.  In this case the orange dots would not be connected to anything as a path cannot exist through them.  Dijkstra's algorithm is very useful for doing what you want, although it's breadth first instead of depth first.  I'd recommend starting there, I'm sure there are examples of that algorithm being implemented in java.

The edges of the graph have weights which are compared in order to find the shortest path between two nodes.

I see that your blocked list declaration has nwq in it instead of new.  That may be your issue right there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at the other algorithm I might understand it better